# AVD Emulator Behind Proxy No Internet

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am currently working on a corporate app which is being developed behind a corporate proxy.

When running the emulator when disconnected from the VPN it has full internet access, when the emulator is being run on the VPN which directs all traffic through a proxy. Proxy information as well as authentication is being set through Android Studio as well as http_proxy / https_proxy environment variables. But the emulator seems to be unable to resolve any urls which are launched.

In the emulator, I have set up a new APN with the corresponding proxy details with the correct authentication

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you change internet/VPN connection after launching AVD it does not work.
Re-launch AVD after internet/VPN change. Hopefully it will work

Comment: I only launch the AVD after connecting to the VPN.

Comment: lol i went to high school with this dude, Yo Ethane C ₂H ₆ Jappiel, did you solve this?

Comment: Holy shit Chris. I ended up ditching the emulator and using a physical device to contact my API directly.